# C++, DeviL, Opengl and msvs2010 - It compiles and links, but cant load entry point in dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, entry-point, devil

I am trying to use the DevIl image library in Windows in my project, using MSVS2010. I have downloaded the sdk "DevIL 1.7.8 SDK for 32-bit Windows" from http://openil.sourceforge.net/download.php and put in a folder where all my others libraries are. I have configured my project to include its headers and to link with the .lib provided. I have copied the dll provided to the folder my .exe is. It compiles and links with no problem but when i try to execute it i have an error popup saying something like "procedure entry point _ilGetData@0 could not be located in DevIl.dll" (translation from spanish). I have followed the same steps as in all libraries i am using with no problems, so i don´t know where the problem is.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the binaries were built with an older version of Visual Studio... you may have to build the library yourself.